# Using highlight-sexp as buffer local

Tags: highlighting

Have been using `highlight-sexp` using hooks

```
(add-hook 'lisp-mode-hook 'highlight-sexp-mode)
(add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook 'highlight-sexp-mode)
```

Would like to enable `highlight-sexp-mode` as buffer local with an `on` and `off` mechanism.  As I am writing this in my init file, the commands should be suitable for inclusion in elisp code, rather than calling `highlight-sex` commands directly in the minibuffer.

Comment: Just do `M-x highlight-sexp-mode` in the target buffer?  Or do I misunderstand what you are after here?

Comment: That's an answer, @FranBurstall (IMO, it's the answer). Please consider posting it as an answer. (Comments can be deleted at any time. Q&A need to stand on their own, to be searchable etc.)

Comment: Not sure I understand.  How are you going to select the buffers where you want to turn the mode on from yr init (which is loaded before those buffers exist)?

Comment: The highlight would be off in init, but will provide interactive functions for switching highlighting on and off for the current buffer.  Because highlight-sexp-mode highlights large chunks I do not want the features enabled by default through a major mode hook or globally.

Comment: There already such a function!  It is called `highlight-sexp-mode` and does *exactly* what you want!  Am I missing something here?

Comment: Yes, but I am also integrating the mode with the `show-paren-mode`.

Comment: I am sorry but I am giving up on this now: I cannot make sense of your intentions.

Comment: Do not delve on the intention but on an `if` condition that checks whether a mode is enabled or not.

Comment: `if` implicit in my answer but now explicit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interactively, just do `M-x highlight-sexp-mode` in the target buffer to toggle the mode.

From elisp,

```
(highlight-sexp-mode 1)
```

turns it on and

```
(highlight-sexp-mode -1)
```

turns it off.  In both cases, this should apply to the current buffer only.

You can detect whether the mode is active by inspecting the value of the *variable* `highlight-sexp-mode` with `C-h v highlight-sexp-mode`.  It will be `t` if the mode is active in the current buffer.  In elisp:

```
(if hightlight-sexp-mode
  (message "it's on!")
 (message "it's off!"))
```

Disclaimer: I do not have this package installed.  I am simply assuming that `highlight-sexp-mode` is a well-behaved minor mode.  You are much better placed to find all this out: simply do `C-h f highlight-sexp-mode` and the docs should tell you, near the top, how to turn on/off from elisp.  Once again: *Ask emacs*.

Comment: In elisp code, would the command be `(highlight-sexp-mode)`.  Would that be only buffer local?  Would need to be able to enable it and disable it.

Comment: Is there a way to determine if a minor mode is active or not?

Comment: See revised version of my answer.

Comment: Thank you.  I would still need an example showing whether the minor-mode is `on` or `off` when done in elisp code.  Because I am focusing on elisp files at this moment that automates the highlighting of exprossions through different settings and functionalities provided by several packages.  Without requiring the user to know all much about the different packages.

Comment: @Ephram: the question has changed a couple of times now.  Please edit yr original question to ask what you *really* want to know.